# How do I replace gitlab.yaml file values using Python and gitlab api's

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab

I'm looking for the best way to update the repo's gitlab.yaml values. So this is my gitlab.yaml file

```
gitlab_job:
  stage: develop
  script:
    - python set_myvar.py
  only:
    - main
```

Here I want to update "main: to "develop", I'm looking for the best way how we can achieve using gitlab api and Python.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs you're looking for are the [Repository files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html). You would essentially use the `Get raw file from repository` to get the current contents of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, do whatever replacements you want (such as `main` -> `develop`), then use the `Update existing file in repository` API to upload the new file into the repository. Note that these are *effectively* git commits behind the scenes, so they will generate a new commit SHA and pipeline in each impacted repository, and will only update the one branch specified in the update call. You can then rebase other active branches if needed.

Comment: You're the man!! 
How do I add the file content to payload?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository

Comment: @AdityaMalviya - You can pass it in on the request JSON using the `content` tag. Otherwise you can use the `commit` APIs if the file is extremely large.